# How do I get the value of a class variable in squeak?

Tags: class, variables, squeak

I have a string that contains the name of a class variable that I know exists for class A. I need to get the value of this variable (i.e. dereferencing), how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
(A bindingOf: #VariableName) value
```